# Can you display an image at specific screen coordinates with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing some code in Python using OpenCV that takes a series of images and processes them. I display the image and the processed image for each image received. My code to display the images is something like this:

```
# Get an image and processes it
cv2.imshow('Raw Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Partially Processed Image', partially_processed_image)
cv2.imshow('Processed Image', processed_image)
cv2.waitkey(0)

# Save result and repeat back through for another image
```

This puts the images all in the same place in the screen on top of each other. Is there a way in OpenCV to display images to different screen locations (so they don't automatically display on top of each other)? I looked in the documentation and didn't see anything immediately obvious, but I wondered if there was a work around.

Thanks!

Comment: See `namedWindow()` and `moveWindow()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment above from Mark Setchell, here is how to display images in OpenCV at specific screen coordinates (check the OpenCV documentation for `namedWindow()` and `moveWindow()` for the version you are using):

```
# Make your windows
cv2.namedWindow('Raw Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('Partially Processed Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('Processed Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

# Get your image and process it
# Then display
cv2.imshow('Raw Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Partially Processed Image', partially_processed_image)
cv2.imshow('Processed Image', processed_image)
# Then move your windows to where you want them
cv2.moveWindow('Raw Image', some_x, some_y)
cv2.moveWindow('Partially Processed Image', some_other_x, some_other_y)
cv2.moveWindow('Processed Image', yet_another_x, yet_another_y)
cv2.waitkey(0)
# Save result and repeat back through for another image
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer but it has a syntax error: It's **waitKey()**, not waitkey().